# IE7 missing Atom feed autodiscovery

Tags: html, feed, autodiscovery, atom-feed

I've been showing a website to a customer who insists on using IE and found out, to my surprise, that IE7 does not autodiscover the Atom newsfeed.

The feed is linked to within the HEAD element of a valid HTML 4.01 Strict page with `<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" href="atom.xml" title="Atom 1.0">`, the link is pointing to the correct URL, the linked feed is a valid Atom 1.0 XML file served as application/atom+xml and contains the correct `<link rel="self">`.

Firefox, Opera, Safari and IE8 beta 2 all do correctly find out the feed and lighten up the relevant address bar button - it's just IE7 that stays greyed out. Same IE7 had no trouble in discovering newsfeeds elsewhere and to pass the HTML part of [DiveIntoMark's autodiscovery test suite](http://diveintomark.org/tests/client/autodiscovery/) with flying colors.

Changing the HREF to a fully qualified URL made no difference, nor did changing the TYPE to a RSS 2.0 MIME or removing the TITLE attribute.

The website address is http://www.monteanalogo.net/.

Any hint about what's wrong here?

Comment: Well, thank you for trying. Doing the same did not solve the problem on my side, but it helped me find out the culprit: my IE7 was lighting up the feed button and all until I clicked to allow the embedded javascript. Digging further the cause seems to be the image viewer modal script. Go figure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I copied your source to my local machine, and IE7's auto-discovery kicked in fine once I changed the href to a full url, rather than a relative one:

```
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" 
          href="http://www.monteanalogo.net/atom.xml" title="Atom 1.0">
```

Needing a full URL seems to be an IE glitch, as the [RFC on atom auto-discovery](http://philringnalda.com/rfc/draft-ietf-atompub-autodiscovery-01.html#anchor10) states that:

> The value MAY be a relative URI, and if so, clients MUST resolve it to a full URI ... using the document's base URI

Microsoft's own [publisher's guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/rssteam/articles/PublishersGuide.aspx) also lists the full url in the `href` tag, but makes no mention of it being compulsory:

> Here is an example of Atom Autodiscovery:
>
> ```
> <head>
>   <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" 
>      title="your feed title here"
>      href= "http://www.company.com/feedurl.xml">
> </head>
> ```